# Moralis-Server in vscode

Tags: javascript, server, blockchain, solidity, moralis

when I type this code ( npm run moralis:sync), I run into this error:

```
my-app@0.1.0 moralis:sync
moralis-admin-cli connect-local-devchain --chain hardhat --moralisSubdomain cxdjddn5lxdh.usemoralis.com --frpcPath ./frp/frpc
```

Starting connection to Hardhat
exec error: Error: Command failed: "./frp/frpc" http -s cxdjddn5lxdh.usemoralis.com:7000 -t GCqiUSu6wG -l 8545 -d cxdjddn5lxdh.usemoralis.com
'"./frp/frpc"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello which version of frp have you installed? Make sure your fprcPath is correct.

Two related threads:

- https://forum.moralis.io/t/unable-to-connect-hardhat-local-node-to-moralis/17154
- https://forum.moralis.io/t/which-frpc-file-to-download-to-connect-moralis-server-to-blockchain/17294/15

If you have more questions or issues with this, you can post on the Moralis forum: https://forum.moralis.io